# Java: Getting an old value after Arraylist.set apply

Tags: java, arraylist

```
    int count=0    
    Position a = sortedlist.get(count);
        if(...)
        {
            System.out.println(sortedlist);
            //change the arraylist index(count) here            
            sortedlist.set(count, new Position(a.start(),sortedlist.get(i).start(),a.height()));
            System.out.println(sortedlist);
            //print out position a, prospected changed value 
            System.out.println(a);
        }
```

the catlog will show

```
[<2.0, 5.0, 4.0>, <4.0, 7.0, 3.0>, <1.0, 3.0, 2.0>, <2.0, 4.0, 1.0>]
[<2.0, 4.0, 4.0>, <4.0, 7.0, 3.0>, <1.0, 3.0, 2.0>, <2.0, 4.0, 1.0>]
<2.0, 5.0, 4.0>
```

Don't know why even after Arraylist element of index0 changed, the a will still remain the original index0 value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your list and your `a` variable both refer (point) to an object, which is elsewhere in memory. Your `set` call puts a reference to a *new* object at that position in the list, which has no effect on the object that `a` is pointing to.

Let's throw some ASCII-Art at it:

**Before `set`:**

```
+------------+
| sortedlist |
+------------+             
| index 0    |------------>+-----------------+
+------------+    +------->|  Position #1    |
                  |        +-----------------+
                  |        | <2.0, 5.0, 4.0> |
                  |        +-----------------+
+-----------+     |
|     a     |-----+
+-----------+
```

**After `set`:**

```
+------------+
| sortedlist |
+------------+             +-----------------+
| index 0    |------------>|  Position #2    |
+------------+             +-----------------+
                           | <2.0, 4.0, 4.0> |
                           +-----------------+

+-----------+              +-----------------+
|     a     |------------->|  Position #1    |
+-----------+              +-----------------+
                           | <2.0, 5.0, 4.0> |
                           +-----------------+
```

If you want both `a` and the list to have an updated position, you have two choices:

1. Update `a` at the same time you update the list, or
2. Don't put a *new* object in the list; instead, change the state of the existing object

Comment: so how can i make `a` changed while that index change? or should i changed a method to do that?

Comment: @atom2ueki: There is no link between the list and the position. You have two choices: 1. Update `a` at the same time you update the list, or 2. Change the *state* of the `Position` object rather than replacing it on the list with a different `Position` object.

Comment: I prefer choose the 1st option, but how can i update position a while the target index element changed?

Comment: @atom2ueki: There's no magic way, you just have to do it in the code. FWIW, it sounds like you want to get rid of the `a` variable entirely, if you're going to be replacing elements in the list and you want those to be the "canonical" ones.

Comment: alright, i know it have to do in the code, but how to set the link reference from `a` to that position? i just don't know how to code that:(

Comment: @atom2ueki: It's just an assignment. After updating the list, you could just do `a = sortedlist.get(0);` again. Or it would be ***slightly*** more efficient to assign the new `Position` object to `a` first and then use `a` when setting it on the list, since you have `a` handy: `a = new Position(a.start(),sortedlist.get(i).start(),a.height());` then `sortedlist.set(0, a);`